# Windows Remote Desktop Printer Redirection is only showing SOME printers

Tags: remote-desktop, terminal-server, printer, windows-server-2022, windows-11

I'm currently having a problem that Printer Redirection over Remote Desktop is only working for **SOME** printers.

Things that I tried and didnt work:

- Restarting the Printer Spooler service
- Restarting UmRdpService, Printer Spooler service
- Group Policy to explicitly disable "Do not allow client printer redirection", "Redirect only the default client printer" & "Use RD Easy Print driver first"
- Log on/off
- installing Windows Updates
- Manually starting the Services:

  - Device Install Service (DeviceInstall)
  - Device Management Enrollment Service
  - Device Setup Manager (DsmSvc)

But still, the Windows server is just showing **some** of the printers of the connected client.
Any help / hints is greatly appreciated!

Some Details:

- Client OS: Windows 11
- Server OS: Windows Server 2022
- Printer that doesn't work: HP Color LaserJet Pro MFPM283FDW
- Printer that work: HP Color LaserJet Pro MFPM183FW

Sources: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c430c930-286a-4e61-822f-a7e56d90fd8d/redirected-printers-not-showing-in-devices-and-printer-unable-to-change-defaults?forum=winserverTS

Comment: Have you checked whether the server perhaps has the driver for the 183 installed on it, but not the 283? Eg, if the issue is with the RDS Easy Print driver then the 183 would work as the server has a driver for it, but the 283 wouldn't.